# How can I ask for user input in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So to start coding I have to ask for a user input. They have to place 4 cards like so

```
A-S,A-H,A-C,A-D
```

Then I would create a list from their input. It should take the 2nd element then the 4th element from their input

```
4cards = input()
List1 = []
List1.append(4cards[1], 4cards[3])
List1pair = ', '.join(P2)
print 'List1 cards: {0}.format(List1pair)'
```

This should or I hope it prints this (I haven't check yet)

```
List1 cards: A-H,A-D
```

But my code returns with a syntax error "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

```
4cards = input()
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: [Identifiers and keywords](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers) - "the valid characters for identifiers are the same as in Python 2.x: the uppercase and lowercase letters A through Z, the underscore _ and, ***except for the first character**, the digits 0 through 9.*"

Comment: oh so my problem was me naming a variable worng

Comment: One of the problems, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"SyntaxError: invalid syntax" shows because variable name can not start with numbers. you can use four_cards instead of 4cards.

```
four_cards = input()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use number first 4cards. Use variable I.E _4cards

```
_4cards = input()
List1 = []
List1.append(_4cards[1], _4cards[3])
List1pair = ', '.join(P2)
print ('List1 cards: {0}.format(List1pair)')
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi The reson you are getting error because of the name of variable `4cards`  we cant use this as a variable name it is starting with a number so you can use `FourCards , Cards4 e.t.c`

Answer (score 0):

variables can not start with numbers
and in python3 print function comes with parentheses : `print(statement)`